# S3 multipart upload - complete multipart upload asyncronously

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I am trying to complete a multipart upload using my lambda (aws) written in python. Below is the code that I am using. There are around 120 parts and combined size is 30GB. The below operation doesn't seem to complete within 5 minutes , hence the lambda shuts down and the upload doesn't seem to complete. Does S3 offer asynchronous multi part upload functionality? I believe this would ensure that the file gets combined irrespective of lambda shutdown.

```
resp = s3.complete_multipart_upload(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=result_filename, UploadId=upload_id, MultipartUpload={'Parts': parts_mapping})
```

Comment: So you're running lots of Lambdas, each uploading a part, and then one final Lambda to complete the multipart upload?

Comment: Yes , that is correct.

Comment: You have two choices: decrease the size of each part or increase the memory size (which increases the network bandwidth) or a combination of both. I am curious on why you have chosen Lambda for this function.

Comment: @JohnHanley thank you. Lambda’s memory size is at max. I have 122 parts each having few 100 MB of data. I thought when I do a multi part upload everything happens behind the scenes within S3 and I was assuming S3 is taking more than 5 mins to process. This is an existing process which works fine for other files which have about 10 Gb of data , hence tried to reuse the same. Doesn’t  S3 support async processing after all the details are passed over to S3 using complete multipart upload api?

Comment: I don't see anything in the boto3 SDK (or more generally in the S3 REST APIs) that would support an async completion of a multipart upload. Given that it can take "a few minutes" to complete and you are clearly exceeding the Lambda 5m timeout, you may have to look for another option (such as EC2 with a userdata script that invokes complete_multipart_upload() and once that completes, shuts down the EC2 instance).

Comment: jarmod , @John Hanley : Thanks for your help. The issue seems to resolved. I was passing incorrect parameter (just passing etag and not part number) in the parts_mapping which was causing the issue. The multi part upload then created the complete file within 30 seconds , once this was fixed. I'm sorry , should have posted a complete example and not wasted your time.

Comment: @PunterVicky - I would edit your question with the complete code (before solution) and then post your own answer identifying the problem section. I think that some people will benefit from this question.

Comment: Sure @JohnHanley , will do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS Lambda limits the maximum execution time of a single invocation to 5 minutes. You can write Lambda functions that perform long-running tasks as **recursive functions.**

```
context.get_remaining_time_in_millis()
```

When your function is invoked, the context object allows you to find out how much time is left in the current invocation.

To minimise the no. of recursions, our function would:

- Limit the size of the part, use small batch.
- At the end of each batch,
  call context.getRemainingTimeInMillis() to check how much time is
  left in this invocation
- If there is more than 1 min left in the
  invocation then process another batch; otherwise recurse

Sample links:
[Recursive Lambda Function](https://labs.ebury.rocks/2016/11/22/recursive-amazon-lambda-functions/) 
[Recursive Lambda the right way](https://theburningmonk.com/2017/08/write-recursive-aws-lambda-functions-the-right-way/)